# Images 404 in Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

My Header images are 404ing only in the OnePage checkout when you view cart or purchase your selected items. As shown in [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtWX4.jpg)

The images are working site-wide except for that page.

The correct path is http://*****.com.au/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/paypal.png

The OnePage Checkout is pointing to http://*****.com.au/checkout/onepage/index/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/paypal.png

/www/checkout does not exist in my folder structure?

Is there a file I can edit to point to the right images

EDIT: This is actually not working in alot of my site. If items are viewed from the homepage it is fine, as soon as I view it from my Categories list, the images are again 404ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe probem in your configuration of Base Skin URL or Base Media URL.
Check your configuration of secure/unsecure url in `System->Configuration->General->Web->Unsecure`

More information you can find [here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/configuration/url-secure-unsecure.html)

Comment: Definitely setup correct as per that link.

Comment: It's look like path to image set incorrectly in your template file, such as <img src="/skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/paypal.png" />, but it must be <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/paypal.png'); ?>" />

Comment: Even if your src didn't correctly use the getSkinUrl function it would seem that the src does not start with a "/"  (which will default to the site root) as the url is just concatenating with the current URL.

Comment: Thankyou my problem was the forward "/" before the src. Fixed.